# Understand lifecycle in Angular component

Tags: angular, lifecycle, angular-components

I'm confused. Based on the lifecycle of this component, it stands to reason that before calling the `setNumbers` method, my array of numbers should be empty, but it is not. I don't know how the `setNumbers` was executed before the console printing. Any explanation for this newbie?

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  numbers: number[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("first", this.numbers);
    this.setNumbers();
  }

  setNumbers() {
    this.numbers.push(1);
  }
}
```

[**Code SandBox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-dream-vbz0k?file=/src/app/app.component.ts:0-372)

Comment: It's important to know how [console.log works with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log#logging_objects). From MDN: "Don't use console.log(obj), use console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))).

This way you are sure you are seeing the value of obj at the moment you log it. Otherwise, many browsers provide a live view that constantly updates as values change. This may not be what you want."

Answer (score 1):

You cannot trust what's written in the console if you are displaying object. Best solution to know what happens in your code is through breakpoint.

Now if you really need to display something in the console, you can stringify the value so it is printed properly : `JSON.stringify(this.numbers)` will display `[]` before the number is set.

Comment: What if I need to do something exactly before the change on the array , I need to know when is the function really called

Comment: You just do it before to call the function. Except for asynchronous actions, what you said about the console.log that should be triggered before the 'setNumbers' is ok. It's just that console.log act in a way you can't be sure what will be displayed. But that's the only case I know about it, everything else works fine.

Comment: Also I recommend you using the Chrome Dev Tools when need further debugging, sometimes logs are tricky. Enable source maps in angular.json, start your app with ng serve and put a breakpoint in the line of code you want to check using the Chrome Dev Tools - Source tab (you can find files with ctrl+p). Mastering the Chrome Dev Tools is very helpful for any issues you will find with Angular and general web development - https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools?hl=es

Comment: @DanielPerales Thanks for the precision, that's what I meant when I said using breakpoint. Also, start your app with the `--aot` option (Especially if Ivy is disabled).